# Creating and serving pdf files from ArcGIS server 10.0

Tags: python, arcgis-server, pdf

I am tasked with sending map data from the Flex client to an MXD then to serve that as a PDF to the client and/or a server side location.  Creating the PDF isn't an issue, however, I am having trouble finding a resource to let you now how to serve it to the client.  Does anyone have any experience of this?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Have you checked the possibility to create PDF in the Export Map REST API? http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisserver/10.0/apis/rest/index.html

Comment: Can you put the PDF in an output folder and navigate the user to the location, like a hyperlink navigation to the PDF file, which will autmatically open in hs browser or Adobe Reader.

Comment: Hi Chaps, I have created some code which updates elements in an MXD and exports them to the server scratch area.  I haven't tried the Flex part yet, but I believe we have to use the call "myMapGP"*.getResultData* call to bring a link back tot he client?  I think this is the way we'll go, unless there are some other ideas.  We can't use the Java back end, as we're running on Python and using toolboxes.  I guess we could try to implement your widget, but it would move us out of our area we're already comitted to

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[This blog post](http://blogs.esri.com/Dev/blogs/arcgisserver/archive/2011/04/12/An-introduction-to-arcpy.mapping-for-ArcGIS-Server-developers.aspx) includes source and produces PDFs; perhaps it can help (at least knowing with how to present the PDF to the user). You basically need to create an output parameter of type file that can be served to the client.

Comment: Thanks Jason, I worked it out this moring and have been tooling around with it all day.  Thanks for your help guys

Answer (score 2):

I developed a Java PrintSOE for the ArcGIS Server:
 http://www.arcgis.com/home/item.html?id=6809086326ea4c76bf026a32bb9dd698

The communication is realized over the Rest API.
So any client can work with it.

There is a Flex widget which demonstrates the functionalities.

Tom

Comment: Thanks Tom, It's not right for us just now, but I will keep this for future use if thats fine?   Cheers P

Comment: +1 for this tool.  Currently trying to help someone getting it running in a distributed (2 SOCs) environment.  Looks like a good tool.